# SP Online - Error deleting a site collection using CSOM

Tags: 2013, office-365, csom

I am trying to delete site collections using CSOM script. Below is the code snippet :

```
using (ClientContext tenantContext = new ClientContext(siteURL))
{
    tenantContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);//new SharePointOnlineCredentials(@"dom\ishan", password);
    var tenant = new Tenant(tenantContext);
    SpoOperation spoOperation = tenant.RemoveSite(siteURL);
    tenantContext.Load(spoOperation);
    tenantContext.ExecuteQuery(); 
}
```

I am getting an error as shown below,  while trying to `tenantContext.ExecuteQuery();`

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerUnauthorizedAccessException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll
>
> Additional information: Access denied. You do not have permission to
>   perform this action or access this resource.

Is there any specific permissions required on farm to work with `Tenant` objects?

**NOTE** : I am Site Collection Admin and i am able to delete the site collection through UI.

Answer (score 2):

To work with the tenant in CSOM, you must have the SharePoint administrator role or the Global Administrator role in Office 365.

There is a command in the [SharePoint Online Management shell](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588) to do this for you, [Remove-SPOSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161377.aspx).

Comment: thanks for your response. I do have admin role at the web app level, is that not enough? I am able to see all the site collections and can go through their settings without being added as Admin.

Comment: then that should be sufficient, updated with a direct way to do it in the Powershell module for SharePoint Online.

Comment: Although i am the global administrator for O365 tenanat , and getting the tenantContext , giving me access denied exception.

Answer (score 0):

you need a username with permissions to remove a site on the site collection. which I believe is Global or SharePoint Online admin.

Here is [very nice code from technet gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Online-Delete-a-e0aabe36)

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

$siteUrl = “https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysitecollection/site1” 
$username = "admin@mytenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
$password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString  
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)  
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username, $password)  
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials 

$web = $ctx.Web  

$ctx.Load($web)  
$ctx.ExecuteQuery() 

$web.DeleteObject() 
$ctx.ExecuteQuery() 
Write-Host $web.Title "Site Deleted"
```

Comment: I am using AD authentication and i do not have online credentials. Do i need to request those separately from Microsoft Support?

Comment: do you have the Sharepoint online admin permission or Tenant admin rights? that is what you need. try the above code with those account

Answer (score 0):

The technique is bit different to access SharePoint Online Credential than onpremises Credential

Authenticate and authorize your credentials this way, it will work

```
using (ClientContext tenantContext = new ClientContext("siteUrl For your Sponlinesite"))
{
    SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in "password".ToCharArray())
    {
         passWord.AppendChar(c);
         tenantContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("UserName", passWord);

         PeopleManager peopleManager = new PeopleManager(tenantContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had already tried this, this does not work with AD credentials.